# email notification in web app: use cron or BCC

Tags: php, email

I am contemplating about the method to use.

it's a system where there is a group with members and would like to email all members when there is a new member.
Now should I create some kind of mail queue and let CRON do it?
Or just put all the email addresses in the BCC.

The rules of BCC should be that it get's stripped of the email so nobody can see who it is.
Standard wise it should work, the thing is...is it a good way to go?

Site is medium sized around 10-40 members per group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you should use cron jobs as it is more feasible than BCC. Cron jobs are defined on the server that can call php script to be used for sending emails. This will also help not the affect the performance of the end user and your script.